# Sorting a networkx graph object Python

Tags: python, networkx

I want to sort a graph object that I have read through networkx library in Python, in the increasing order of edgeweight. It seems that the `sort` command of python won't apply to graph objects. I am sure there is a easy way to sort this object, but I am not sure how. Any help will be appreciated.

For example, my first three edges are

```
1 3 5250
1 4 74
1 5 3659
```

After sorting I would hope that their order is changed to

```
1 4 74
1 5 3659
1 3 5250
```

Here is my code so far

```
import networkx as nx
g=nx.read_weighted_edgelist(fname,nodetype=int)
```

I am trying to sort the object `g`.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "sort a graph object"?  Get a list of edges ordered by increasing edge weight?  Get a list of nodes ordered by increasing sum of edge weight over all edges?  By maximal edge weight?  Etc.

Comment: I need to get the list of edges ordered by increasing edge weight. I will update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
import networkx as nx
edgelist = [
    (1, 3, {'weight':5250}),
    (1, 4, {'weight': 74}),
    (1, 5, {'weight': 3659})]

G = nx.Graph(edgelist)
for a, b, data in sorted(G.edges(data=True), key=lambda x: x[2]['weight']):
    print('{a} {b} {w}'.format(a=a, b=b, w=data['weight']))
```

yields

```
1 4 74
1 5 3659
1 3 5250
```

Comment: This does the sort, but now the object is no longer a graph object. Is it possible to retain the object as an graph object.

Comment: `G` is still a `Graph` object. You can access the edges with `G[a][b]`.

Comment: I have used a Direct Graph. The for loop seems to be giving a invalid syntax error in Python 3. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Bonson: Thanks for the alert. In Python3, [tuple parameter unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax) has been removed. I've updated the code above for Python3.

Answer (score 6):

The built-in `sort` function has a `key` parameter that takes a function. If it is specified, sort will sort the collection according to the order of the result of application of the key function to the original elements.

```
>>> sorted([1,2,3], key=lambda x:-x)
[3, 2, 1]
```

You can find more information [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions)

In your particular case, if you need to sort by edge weight and you have a list of edges, you need to provide the function that maps an edge to its weight:

```
sorted( list_of_edges, key= lambda edge: edge['weight'] )
```

Comment: It seems that the `sort` does not apply to graph object. When i tried `g.sort()` I got an error `'Graph' object has no attribute 'sort'`

Comment: @hardikudeshi indeed, it's not a function of `Graph`, though it is of some built-in types like `list`. You can still use the `sorted` function, though